# Show that $x\mapsto x + \int_x^\infty \left( \frac{f(t)}{f(x)} \right)^2\; dx$ is onto $(0,\infty)$

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

Looking at a paper, a statement mentions that some parameter $\lambda=\lambda(t)$ (for any $t>0$) is implicitly defined by the equation
$$
t^2 = \lambda + \int_\lambda^\infty \left( \frac{f(x)}{f(\lambda)} \right)^2\; dx
$$
where $f\in L_1(0,\infty)+L_2(0,\infty)$ is a decreasing function (so that the above is well-defined). Now, this may be obvious, but since $t\in(0,\infty)$ is arbitrary, this requires that the function 
$\Phi_f\colon x\in(0,\infty)\mapsto x + \int_x^\infty \left( \frac{f(t)}{f(x)} \right)^2\; dt$ be onto $(0,\infty)$.

Is that clear? I cannot really see why; in particular, this does hold for all $f$'s of the form $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{1/2+\alpha}}$ ($\alpha>0$), for instance; then one gets a linear function.

But if I take $f(x) = e^{-x}$ (which is in $L_1+L_2)$, then $\Phi_f(x) = x+\frac{1}{2}$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$ \tag1\Phi_f(x)=x+\frac{\int_x^\infty f(t)^2\,\mathrm dt}{f(x)^2}$$
and so
$$\tag2\begin{align}\Phi_f'(x)&=1+\frac{\int_x^\infty f(t)^2\,\mathrm dt\cdot 2f(x)-(-f(x)^2)\cdot f(x)^2}{f(x)^4} \\&=2+\frac2{f(x)^3}\int_x^\infty f(t)^2\,\mathrm dt.\end{align}$$
Since $f$ is decreasing to $0$, it must be positive, so the we conclude that $\Phi_f'(x)>2$. Therefore,  $\Phi_f$ maps $[a,\infty)$ onto $[\Phi_f(a),\infty)$ for any $a>0$.
Thus for desired property is equivalent to $$\tag3\lim_{x\to0^+}\Phi_f(x)=0$$
and hence to
$$\tag4\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=+\infty.$$
This condition holds for $f(x)=\frac1{x^{1/2+\alpha}}$, but not for $f(x)=e^{-x}$, matching your observations.

So check back with the text if you are not missing that they have $(4)$ as additional condition.

Comment: Thank you! I have checked again, I cannot see this condition (it's Theorem 1 in [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021904586900547)). It might be the case that they left out the case $\lambda \leq 0$ (in the proof) untreated (?).